# Training YOLO on YOLO results

Tags: machine-learning, datasets, yolo, fine-tuning

I have a large unlabelled dataset. What if I use YOLO to label it? Will this dataset be useful to train a better YOLO model? What if I then finetune it on a smaller labelled dataset? My usecase requires training YOLO from scratch, as finetuning a pretrained model yields worse results.